# Passing args, kwargs, to run_in_executor

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to pass arguments to `run_in_executor` like so:

```
    loop.run_in_executor(None, update_contacts, data={
        'email': email,
        'access_token': g.tokens['access_token']
    })
```

However, I get the following error:

> run_in_executor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'

Is there a generic way to pass args to this function?

Comment: what is the definition of `update_contacts`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `functools.partial`; it's a standard way to do such things, and it's specifically recommended in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) for `loop.run_in_executor`, as well as more generally in [the Event Loop docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio-pass-keywords).

Here's how it might look for you:

```
import functools  # at the top with the other imports

loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(update_contacts, data={
    'email': email,
    'access_token': g.tokens['access_token']
}))
```

You could also do `from functools import partial`, if you like.

Answer (score 10):

You asked for a "generic way"; the most generic answer is that you create a function for the purpose.  If the `data` you want to provide is local to the caller, you create that function inside the caller, perhaps as a lambda:

```
loop.run_in_executor(None,lambda: update_contacts(data={
  'email': email,
  'access_token': g.tokens['access_token']
})
```

As given, this is not much different from the `functools.partial` answer, and (as the documentation says) it might reduce the utility of debug output, but it lets you do things like compute the `data` values on the executor and act on the return value from `update_contacts`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that calls it:

```py
def foo():
    update_contacts(data={'email': email,'access_token': g.tokens['access_token']})
loop.run_in_executor(None, foo)
```

**or**, the func could also be lambda:

```py
loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: update_contacts(data={'email': email,'access_token': g.tokens['access_token']})
```

or use fuctools

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with the generic path what I do is
loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda data: update_contacts(**data), {
'email': email,
'access_token': g.tokens['access_token']
})

Then I do not need to use any extra imports.